# Is there a way to nest a loop in JavaScript until a condition is met? Like a while loop but nested?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to code an algorithm that tests to see if a game is possible to be won, given a randomly shuffled deck. I came up with a super simplified solitaire-esque game with like 15 cards, because I'm just messing around and I don't want to try a game with too many options until I've figured out a way to do it. My goal is to test every possible combination of moves, so I wrote a function that returns an array of possible moves when given the state of the board. What I need help with is calling that function every time I change the board. Right now my code calling the function looks like this:

```
let moves = possibleMoves(piles);
if (moves.length >= 1){
  for (let move of moves) {
    let nB = piles.slice(0);
    nB[move.from].pop();
    nB[move.to].push({card: move.card, x: move.to, y: nB[move.to].length});
    let m0s = possibleMoves(nB);
    if (m0s.length >= 1) {
      for (let m0 of m0s){
        let nB0 = nB.slice(0);
        nB0[m0.from].pop();
        nB0[m0.to].push({card: m0.card, x: m0.to, y: nB0[m0.to].length})
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But obviously I can't just nest that loop infinitely until there are no possible moves (note, I still haven't written code for when there are no possible moves but I'll get to it). The reason I can't just do a while loop is because I want to check every possible move after every possible move, without actually changing the board. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: a recursive function maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive function maybe what you are looking for

```
function recursive(piles){
let moves = possibleMoves(piles);
if (moves.length >= 1){
  for (let move of moves) {
    let nB = piles.slice(0);
    nB[move.from].pop();
    nB[move.to].push({card: move.card, x: move.to, y: nB[move.to].length});
    recursive(nB)
  }
}else{
return;
}}
```